# Get data from php file to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

The javascript below is supposed to be some sort of autocomplete. I am using bootstrap typeahead.

When I type items in my input field, I am able to see suggestions, the problem is I am not able to select them and populate the input field.
Any idea what may be wrong with it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#typeahead').typeahead({
    source:  function (query, process) {
         objects = [];
         map = {};

        return $.get('live_search.php?filter=relation', { query: query }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                return process(data);   
            });


            $.each(data, function(i, object) {
            map[object.name] = object;
            objects.push(object.name);
            });

            process(objects);

    },
    updater: function(item) {
        $('#getSelection').val(map[item].name);
        $('#getValue').val(map[item].name);
        return item;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Teemu How is it a duplicate of that one???

Comment: You've a return statement in the callback function, read the dup and you'll understand.

Comment: @Teemu I am able to return the data in two different ways, my problem is not that. Please before you mark it as a duplicate, read it!

Comment: @Teemu and you better read my question. My question is how to return the data from a php file basically, not how to in general.

Comment: You're not be able to return data to any receiver you could access from the callback function of the asynchronous function call. And `echo` is pretty much the most used PHP statement when returning data to an ajax call.

Comment: @Teemu I find your intervention quite inappropriate frankly. My question is more specific, and if you cannot see that, then fine

Comment: Well, it's your code and your problem, as you wish ...

Comment: @Teemu I did some modifications to the question, since maybe I wasn't that clear in the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your source method returns immediately from the $.get call and never enters the $.each iteration. Move the iteration code into the get request callback block.

Also you're references to `objects` and `map` are in the scope of the `source` method, but you reference them in the `updater` method

```
var typeahead = {
  objects: [],
  map: {},
};

$("#typeahead").typeahead({
  source: function(query, process) {
    return $.get("live_search.php?filter=relation", { query: query }, function(
      data
    ) {
      var data = $.parseJSON(data);

      $.each(data, function(i, object) {
        typeahead.map[object.name] = object;
        typeahead.objects.push(object.name);
      });

      return process(data);
    });
  },
  updater: function(item) {
    $("#getSelection").val(typeahead.map[item].name);
    $("#getValue").val(typeahead.map[item].name);
    return item;
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks but still not working, or maybe I am doing smth wrong. I am quite bad with javascript.

Comment: Can you maybe help me to rewrite this part?

Comment: Which plugin are you using, @DaniM?

Comment: I am using typeahead plugin, from bootstrap

Comment: I tried the above code and still it doesn't work. When I select the suggestion, it isn't inserted in the input